# Not able to fetch the image for twitter sharing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to call the image while sharing on twitter.

I have created some code and working fine for title sharing. I have used Meta tag also.

please look into my code.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://html5andcss3.org/images/facebook_html5.png">

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">

<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://html5andcss3.org/images/facebook_html5.png">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Html5andCss31">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Html5andCss31">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="">
```

and then jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#twitter_share').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = "https://html5andcss3.org/userdata/" + getLINK;
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + title + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 225) + ', left=' + $(window).width() / 3 + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
  });   
});
```

and finally HTML code

```
<i id="twitter_share" class="fa fa-twitter-square fs20 fa-3x"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : I resolved it myself

```
<meta name="twitter:title" content=$title>
```

This tag resolves all the issue